# change active step title color on asp wizard

Tags: css, asp.net

i got stuck to change a color on asp wizard when active step has activated i tried to solved  by use CSS  like this

CSS

```
.wizard1 a:active
   {
          color:red;
          font-weight:bold;
   }
```

ASP

```
 <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" CssClass="valign-table"  ActiveStepIndex="0" >
          <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Top"  />
        <SideBarStyle VerticalAlign="Top" Width="100px" BorderStyle="None"  />
        <StepStyle VerticalAlign="Top"/>
 <WizardSteps>
         <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server"  Title="๑. Producer Info"  StepType="Start">
```

but there is not anything happened to change step title to red 
 when step has activated

Comment: Thank you @joshua  but i solved by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668257/vb-net-using-wizard-changing-selected-side-bar-button-color

Answer (score 0):

well first off from looking at your code i see you have .wizard1 , and in your html code it is Wizard1 with a capital W, try making them both the same and that should help.. bellow are some more examples of what you can do

Example

Select and style a

,  and  element when you click on it:

```
p:active, h1:active, a:active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Example

Select and style unvisited, visited, hover, and active links:

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link    {
    color: green;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover   {
    color: red;
}
```

Example

Style links with different styles:

```
/* selected link */
a:active  {
    color: yellow;
}

a.ex1:hover, a.ex1:active {
    color: red;
}

a.ex2:hover, a.ex2:active {
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go.. working code,

css

```
#menuleft ul{
    position:absolute;
    width:160px;
    top:61px;
    left:50;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
```

html

```
<div id="menuleft">
    <div class="top">header</div>
<ul>
<li>
  <li><a href="#">Main 1</a>
<li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
      </ul>
<li>
<li><a href="#">Main 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Main 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Main 4</a></li>
<li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```